# Getting Exception while writing Dataset to Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming

I am trying to write DataSet to Hive database by using Spark Java, but while in the process I am getting Exception.

This is my code:

```
 Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().json(rdd).select("event.event_name");
 data.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("telecom.t2");
```

Here, `rdd` is the streamed json data and I can able to print the result `data` by following command.

```
data.show();
```

But when i try to write this result into Hive database i am not getting any exceptions but i am getting Exception in `Hive command line` when i try to print those values. For eg:

```
select * from telecom.t2;
```

And the exception is:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:317)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:219)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:44)
    at parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:62)
    at parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(NonBlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(BytesInput.java:204)
    at parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:89)
    at parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:72)
    at parquet.column.Encoding$1.initDictionary(Encoding.java:89)
    at parquet.column.Encoding$4.initDictionary(Encoding.java:148)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.<init>(ColumnReaderImpl.java:337)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.newMemColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:66)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.getColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:61)
    at parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:270)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:134)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:99)
    at parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$NoOpFilter.accept(FilterCompat.java:154)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:99)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:137)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:208)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNativeLoader.loadLibrary(SnappyNativeLoader.java:52)
    ... 48 more
Exception in thread "main" org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] null
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:229)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:44)
    at parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:62)
    at parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(NonBlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(BytesInput.java:204)
    at parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:89)
    at parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:72)
    at parquet.column.Encoding$1.initDictionary(Encoding.java:89)
    at parquet.column.Encoding$4.initDictionary(Encoding.java:148)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.<init>(ColumnReaderImpl.java:337)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.newMemColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:66)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReadStoreImpl.getColumnReader(ColumnReadStoreImpl.java:61)
    at parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:270)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:134)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:99)
    at parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$NoOpFilter.accept(FilterCompat.java:154)
    at parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:99)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:137)
    at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:208)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.read.ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.<init>(ParquetRecordReaderWrapper.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
2 Jan, 2017 12:02:40 PM WARNING: parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
2 Jan, 2017 12:02:40 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: RecordReader initialized will read a total of 12 records.
2 Jan, 2017 12:02:40 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
2 Jan, 2017 12:02:40 PM INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 29 ms. row count = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark saves data in `parquet.snappy` format by default when you call `saveAsTable` and it seems you don't have snappy in hive library path. Changing writer format (for example to `json`) will not work because Hive expects sequence files in table created using this option.

But you can change compression algorithm before saving data as table:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip")
```

Gzip compression should be available on Hive by default, in case of any problems you can still save data without compression:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "uncompressed")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mariusz, when i tried as you said i am getting following exception in hive:* Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/telecom.db/t2/part-r-00000-0bd1c641-0e4d-4a8c-98a3-b8d31ecd4172.json not a SequenceFile*

Comment: CREATE TABLE `t2`(
  `event_name` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'path'='hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/telecom.db/t2') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse/telecom.db/t2'

Comment: TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'EXTERNAL'='FALSE', 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='-1', 
  'rawDataSize'='-1', 
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='parquet', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"event_name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}', 
  'totalSize'='1134', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1483342731')
Time taken: 0.578 seconds, Fetched: 23 row(s)

Comment: You are right, Hive have some problems reading tables with changed format. Try changing the compression method from snappy to gzip - please see my updated answer.

Comment: getting same exception

Comment: Ensure you have no `format` specified not or the format is forced to parquet: `.format("parquet")`

Answer (score 0):

This error

> org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] null

is related to snappy issue https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/6

In last comment of this issue, there is a workaround:

```
unzip snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
cd org/xerial/snappy/native/Mac/x86_64/
cp libsnappyjava.jnilib libsnappyjava.dylib
cd ../../../../../..
cp snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar.old
jar cf snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar org
```